# System.IndexOutOfRangeException error when attempting to convert file into dictionary

Tags: .net

Here you can see the code:

```
Dictionary<string, long> PhoneBook = new Dictionary<string, long>();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\phones.txt");
        PhoneBook = lines.Select(l => l.Split('='))
            .ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => Convert.ToInt64(a[1]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `ToDictionary` call is that you assume that all lines are non-empty. When you call `Split` with an empty line, you get an array of size zero.

Fix this by adding a `Where` after `Select` to drop zero-length arrays:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\phones.txt");
var phoneBook = lines
    .Select(l => l.Split('='))
    .Where(a => a.Length >= 2)
    .ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => Convert.ToInt64(a[1]));
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I still continue to get the same error for some reason :(

Comment: Or even check that the length is exactly 2

Comment: Sorry, your solution did help. After I changed the file to read from, it started working fine.